# Declarar un arraylist global

Tags: java, java-swing, arraylist, variables-globales

Tengo el siguiente problema

Estoy intentando declarar un arraylist global para meter objetos de tipo persona, cuando quiero utilizarlo haciendo un extends de la clase donde lo tengo declarado, se me mezclan los componentes de cada frame que son las clases en las que quiero usar el arraylist.

Si necesitan código lo subo, ahora no me deja, me dice que el mensaje es mucho código

Como podría solucionar el problema?

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Si estas trabajando entre `Frames` o Clases podrías por ejemplo mandar ese `ArrayList` al constructor de la Clase o `Frame` receptor, de esta manera trabajas con el mismo arreglo en diferentes clases, enviando solo el arreglo al constructor te evitas de implementar todos los métodos y atributos.

ejemplo:

```
public class ClaseA (){
ArrayList<Object> lista = new ArrayList();

public ClaseA(){

}

}
```

/*/*/*/*/**/**/*/

```
public class ClaseB (){
ArrayList<Object> lista;

public ClaseA(ArrayList recibirLista){
      this.lista = recibirLista;
}

}
```

Otra manera menos práctica es definir ese `ArrayList` como `public Static` y con eso ya puedes acceder a él sin necesidad de implementar la clase o enviarlo por constructor, pero creo que no es una buena práctica.
y accedes mediante:

```
Clase.nombreArreglo.metodo();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola gracias por responder

Eso lo intente pero me da un error que no se como arreglar, me queda algo asi

```
    public Cframe(ArrayList clientes) { // Cframe lo creo en el frame principal
        initComponents();       
    }

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() { // En este metodo que no se que hace  me da el error
       public void run() {
         new Cframe(clientes).setVisible(true); // Aca me dice que no puedo referenciar una variable no estática en un contexto estático
       }
     });
```

No se si puedo volar el metodo que me da problemas, porque no se que hace si al "Cframe" lo creo y lo hago visible desde el frame principal

Saludos